Compact set of Irrational number is nowhere dense
I am trying to show that:
Let $(\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}, \tau_d)$ be the irrational number space under the Euclidean topology $\tau_d$.
Let $S \subseteq \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ be a compact set of $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$.
Then $S$ is nowhere dense in $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$.
Then I try to show that the interior of $S$ is the empty set.
By definition, the $\textit{int}S = \cup_i\{(a_i,b_i)\cap \mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q} : (a_i,b_i)\cap \mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}\subset S\}$.
To show the interior is empty, I guess we have to show that such $(a_i,b_i)\cap \mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}$ contained in S is empty.
But I am unsure how to proceed from here.
Any insight will be appreciated! :)

Hint: assume to the contrary that for some $a < b$, $(a, b) \cap \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q} \subset S$. By density of irrationals in all real numbers, there exists a sequence $(r_n)$ in $(a, b) \cap \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ - and thus also in $S$ - such that $r_n \to q$ in $\mathbb{R}$ for some rational $q$. However, $S$ is compact, so there is a subsequence of $(r_n)$ that converges to some $q’ \in S \subset \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$. Is this possible?

Thank you so much! This is very helpful!
